# swagger not showing HttpGet query parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on asp.net core webapi(6.0) with swagger. When I run the application HttpGet method **Parameters** summary not visible in swagger. such as Id, StoreId, DateFrom, DateTo summary not display in swagger. Please advice

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Get product details.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Fetches product.</remarks>
    /// <param name="parameters"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <response code="200">Successful Response</response>
    /// <response code="400">Bad Request</response>
    /// <response code="401">Unauthorized</response>
    /// <response code="424">Failed Dependency</response>
    /// <response code="500">Internal Server Error</response>
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetProduct([FromQuery] Parameter parameters)
        {
            var repo = await Repository.GetAllAsync(parameters);
            return Ok()
        }



public class Parameter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Product Id
    /// </summary>
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Optional Parameter. If supplied, result set will be restricted to the products from the supplied store alone
    /// </summary>
    public int? StoreId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Optional Parameter.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Optional Parameter.
    /// </summary>
public DateTime? DateTo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`XML comments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#xml-comments) can be used to add parameters to the swagger UI.

First enable `GenerateDocumentationFile` in your .csproj file to generate xml documentation file, which will be used in swagger json generation.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Then config the swagger service to `IncludeXmlComments` from the genreated xml docs file:

```
//builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    // using System.Reflection;
    var xmlFilename = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFilename));
});
```

the result:
[image]

Comment: My solution has multiple project such as

Main.API
Main.Core
Main.API.Test
Main.Infracture

If I keep Parameter class is in Main.Core project. swagger does not work. but when I keep in Parameter class in Main.API swagger works. Any idea

Comment: @itmannz Swagger is an Interface Description Language for describing RESTful APIs expressed using JSON.  In a word, swagger is to serve webapi, and other projects should also be available if needed.

Comment: Hi Json Pan

I have tried with classLibrary2.xml  (Main.Core project) it's working fine but 

    //var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                //var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                //s.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);

                var xmlFile2 = $"ClassLibrary2.xml";
                var xmlPath2 = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile2);
                s.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath2);

Comment: Hi Json Pan

I have tried with Main.Core.xml  (Class library project) it's working fine but I have to comment Main.API project (webapi project)

How can I include both xml? please advice
Main.API project : 
    //var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    //var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
    //s.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);

    var xmlFile2 = $"Main.Core.xml";
    var xmlPath2 = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile2);
    s.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath2);

Comment: @itmannz just ask a new question instead

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,
-Generate xml doc file other project true as well where you have xml documentation for parameters.

- you can add as many xml documentation files in StartUp.cs using .IncludeXmlComments (if 2, add two .IncludeXmlComments)
- Swagger will combine all files and show the result.

Answer (score 0):

For me all 3 QueryParam were not showing up.
so, I realised, I duplicated the name(s).
On fixing that all QueryParam(s) were being shown on swagger.
For instance::

@NotNull @QueryParam("rId") Long rId,
@NotNull @QueryParam("pId") Long pId,
@NotNull @QueryParam("pId") Integer cpId //repeater here, fixing this fixed the issue for me.

Additionally, the annotation were of jersey, you could check on same lines.